# Is Claptrap's action skill entirely random?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

When Claptrap uses his action skill, it will cause one of several outcomes, such as Torgue Fiesta or Pirate Ship Mode.

Are all of the VaultHunter.exe outcomes equally likely?  Are some outcomes more likely in certain situations, such as depleted shields or empty ammo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/VaultHunter.EXE):

> VaultHunter.EXE will analyse the situation, and will bestow a "Action
>   Package" depending on the criteria met

It seems like outcomes are more likely in certain situations.

In my own experience, I have noticed that some abilities definitely happen more than others like Miniontrap and Mechromagician. I believe it's my play-style that keeps getting me in the same kind of trouble.

I would like to know more info about the "criteria" that needs to be met, but I haven't been able to find any details about that.

Comment: Additionally, look at the Sensless Sacrifice action package: "Claptrap downs himself to revive all other team members that are currently downed." Not only does this only happen during co-op, it almost certainly isn't selected unless you have teammates down.